# Assign a specific date to a Datetime field in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo

I have a field "date_order" of type "fields.Datetime" and I would like to assign a specific date to that field.

So how do I do to do:

```
self.date_order = "October 19th, 1987 00:00h"
```

Odoo 10

Comment: try to assign like this --> "1987-18-10 00:00:00"

Comment: you can't assign October 19th, 1987 00:00h to a datetime field. Because this will be considered as characters not as datetime object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign in "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS" format

```
self.date_order = '1987-10-19 00:00:00'
```